# Fill cells with pattern-color and overlay with background color

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

**Problem solved, probably a bug. Check comment!**

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/OizqFlMtZLQ?si=Anoc-iG-iYWw9OHs&t=9627) guide to make a Gantt-workbook. At the timestamp (also in the link) 2:40:27 the instructor is wanting to fill some cells based on a formula with a pattern-fill. Some of these cells might (sometimes) also be filled with another color later on, to illustrate two timelines merging.

However, when I try to do the same thing. My pattern-fill rule overlays the background-color-fill rule (which is applaied after). See pictures for more info.

**As an exmple for now, just focus on row 15 (id 1)**

The blue arrow indicates where the blue cells (bar) should start overlaying the grey-pattern-fill. However, for me the grey-pattern-fill overlays the blue-background-color. You can also see the two rules marked in the list with a red x.
[image: Picture that shows expected overlay and the rules related.]

The following formulas make up the rules

```
=AND(display="Plan vs Base", itemInBase, OR(type="T",type="S"))
=colorCode=101
```

So to my question, what might be wrong? Is there a setting or something in my workbook that a cell can't have more than one fill?

One solution is add to my formula so that I am not pattern-filling cells which is in the other timeline. However, I want the to be able to vizualize it the same way as in the video. As where the two timelines are overlaying eachother I will have a darker color.

**Proof of bug**

Proof that it is a bug. As you can see on the picture above, I do not have "Stop If True" checked in the first rule marked with a red X. This would indeed stop it checking for the second marked rule with the other red X in the picture. You can also see that the "apply" button has been pressed. To demostrate this I add another picture now when it is working and the same two rules are marked again. (some more rules has been added however, these were added after I solved this problem by removing then adding the rule again).

[image: Proof of bug]

Comment: Potential bug! I copy-pasted the rule formula and removed the rule, added it again with the same patter-fill. Now it is working like a charm.

Comment: Remove the check mark in the `Stop if True` for all rules you want to take effect on the cell (overlap/merge) at the same time. This cannot be visualized though with `Solid Fill`.

Comment: When you add a new rule `Stop if True` by default is uncheked that is why it works. So I also think it is not a bug but as what @Notus_Panda posted in his answer, it is a feature.

Comment: @L42 I have now added another picture and more text to show you that I have indeed not selected "Stop if True" in the first case. I know about this options and even toggled it ON/OFF (with Apply between)

Answer (score 0):

The order of your rules matter. **EDIT**: "but pattern can overlap color so it should have been ok"

From [Ablebits](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-conditional-formatting/#:%7E:text=The%20Stop%20If%20True%20option,the%20first%20rule%20is%20activated.):
*The Stop If True option in conditional formatting prevents Excel from processing other rules when a condition in the current rule is met. In other words, if two or more rules are set for the same cell and Stop if True is enabled for the first rule, the subsequent rules are disregarded after the first rule is activated.*

Hence the reason why you have the up/down arrows next to "Duplicate Rule". Basically, the "Stop if" counts for the following rules and the rules are processed up to down.
[image]

Here an example as how it matters:
[image]

This should explain why it isn't a bug but a feature (as annoying as that may sound :p )

Comment: I have now added another picture and more text to show you that I have indeed not selected "Stop if True" in the first case. I know about this option and even toggled it ON/OFF (with Apply between)

Comment: Me explaining the Stop If was because I saw it being selected in the lower rules but I think your issue stemmed from the position of the rules rather than that. The higher the rule, the more its priority in what is shown, i.e. `Left($B2,1) = 1` is first in the rule, then it'll keep the color of that rule over the following rule `$B2 = 100` hence the lack of yellow in the B-column in my example. As L42 mentioned however, there's no visual overlap possible in the background-color.

Comment: I am telling you that I removed the rule, added it again, in the same position/order and it worked. I even tried it now again to move the rule up to the same position as in the first picture and it still works.

Comment: Oh; pattern != fill color in terms of overlap apparently, good to know! Then I retract my statement that it was the order since those rules can co-exist in the cell.